# Can anyone tell me how to test a Web page for Cross Browser Issues

Tags: xhtml

Hi
I am fairly new to Web Development. I have a page that is hand coded in xHTML/CSS and i want to test it for Cross Browsers Interoperability. Many thanks for reading and do reply

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if your asking for something deeper here..

but can't you just open your webpage in the big 4? Firefox, Internet Explorer, Chrome and Safari?

Note different versions of IE have some issues too.

I'm not aware of a singular platform that will test your page for all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Install all the relavent browsers (using the [IEVMs](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=21eabb90-958f-4b64-b5f1-73d0a413c8ef&displaylang=en) for MSIE) and then just test.

Answer (score 0):

I have usually several browsers installed and just check in them. Not sure how would you do some automated test though. The issues are often in the UI (can't see something, overlapping elements) and this needs to be human-checked anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This is only for versions of IE, but considering how different IE6, 7 and 8 function and render (you can also test in older versions, but I don't see a need these days), it's still indispensable.  You can download the exe here:

http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage